# Почему ajax запросы к базе быстрее, чем голый javascript по всем данным сразу?

Tags: javascript, сортировка, sqlite3, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер

Почему запросы к базе для примитивной сортировке по integer полям быстрее, чем сортировка самого javascript?

- У меня sqlite3 база с 12k записями - 5 мегабайт.
- У каждой записи есть несколько integer полей с числами в диапазоне от 0 до 100.
- Сортировка проводится по asc / desc случайным образом по разным полям.

Я использую datatables.net фрэйм-ворк. Если я загружаю **сразу** всю базу в таблицу - сортировка по int полям занимает *десятки секунд*!

А если я использую [server-side](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/18376/sqlite-version-of-php-processing-code) скрипт, который выполняет несколько sql запросов к sqlite.db, то такая сортировка выполняется меньше секунды.

Ведь это же обычная сортировка int-ов.

В случае чистого клиента, одного лишь javascript - у браузера уже все данные на борту, ему нужно лишь сортировать integer, это же выполняется теми же самими скоростными методами достаточно низкого уровня, что и у sqlite. В чём же тут sqlite может выиграть у js?

А в случае ajax, браузеру надо спросить apache, подождать, php спросит sqlite3, тот проделает тот же самый пузырёк по int-ам, данные вернутся в php, и только потом apache.

Почему javascript такой тормозной? Мне казалось, что такие вещи как сортировка int-ов не должны уступать Обычным C/C++, ведь всё это обёрнуто во встроенные методы на том же самом C/C++.

Я понимаю, если бы это были гигабайты - браузер бы не удержал, но 5 мегабайт, почему так?

Comment: Если пытаться сравнивать, надо увидеть еще и как ты сортируешь на клиенте. И нет ли в базе случайно индексов по тем полям, по которым идет сортировка. По индексу же данные берутся уже отсортированными

Comment: пузырек по интам? серьезно? :)

Comment: И кстати JS в принципе не может сортировать int, потому как у него просто нет такого типа данных :) он же не типизированный, у него int - это объект. массив это объект. А объект - ассоциативный массив. поиск по ключу там конечно каким нибудь B-деревом делается, а вот перемещать эти элементы с перебалансировкой этого самого дерева - не самая быстрая операция, даже если дерево красно-черное

Comment: @Mike, ну на клиенте datatables.net, на сервере sqlite3. Впринципе datatables - достаточно развитая штука, что бы упустить какую-то опцию javascript-а в таком вопросе. А вот про то, что в js нет int-а, не знал. Видимо это и есть загвоздка.

Comment: У меня была точно такая же сортировка datatables, и тоже тормозило всё на гораздо меньшем числе записей, пришлось переделать на серверную сортировку. Короче несмотря на заявляемую скорость джаваскрипт рендеры те еще тормоза. Быстрее сотрировать и рендерить на серваке

Comment: Там datatables грубо говоря проходил по всем строкам таблицы, находил нужную колоночку, силой неимоверных усилий доставал оттуда нужное значение, десять раз конвертировал, потом это всё дело сортировал, ну и короче в итоге это все тормозило на не особо быстрых машинах или в IE что мама не горюй.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript очень гибкий язык, любому объекту можно добавлять свойства на лету. Значения этих свойств можно задавать любыми, сейчас это число, а в следующей строке программы присваиваешь указатель на объект.

По факту в JS абсолютно все - это объекты. Числа - это объекты, массивы - это то же объекты. Возьмем `var a=new Array; a[10000000]=1;` в массиве мгновенно появляется элемент с индексом 10млн и память это занимает только под 1 объект.

Практически единственным способом поддержки такого поведения является ведение списка указателей на объекты. А для быстрого доступа по произвольным (в т.ч. текстовым) ключам, да еще значения которых программа может собрать динамически, на лету, является двоичное дерево. Оно дает очень быстрый поиск по своему ключу, но вот добавление элементов в него это не самая быстрая операция.

А любая сортировка по значениям объектов хранящихся по ссылкам в дереве - это полная перестройка двоичного дерева. Плюс к этому прикладная библиотека, та же datatables.net как то по своему хранит данные и еще надо посмотреть как она их сортирует ... Беглый просмотр исходников показал наличие десятка методов сортировки в этой библиотеке. А у самого javascript он только один. Что то мне подсказывает, что сортируют они данные отнюдь не вызовом библиотечных функций, а делают это операторами JS, по сути по одному передвигая элементы в массиве (а значит и в двоичном дереве), что приводит к гигантским накладным расходам по перебалансировке дерева.